# Entity Framework 6 Code Generation - Change Naming Conventions

Tags: .net, vb.net, entity-framework

Is it possible for Entity Framework to generate classes with a different naming convention than what the database uses?

My database tables and columns are named like this: ABC_XYZ
My .NET code uses pascal case, so that same table would have an associated class titled AbcXyz.

I have tried database-first using T4 templates.  I have also tried data annotations.  With or without the data annotations, I get the error: "The entity type AbcXyz is not part of the model for the current context."

I am going to try the code first option, but it appears I will have to manually enter all of the data annotations.  Assuming it works, this is an OK solution but not ideal because it will require a significant amount of manual coding (I have a lot of tables to work with).

Edited to make question more clear.

Answer (score 0):

check if DBContext is generating right Code with wright table name and also you can modify T4 for model to define the table name

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you.  The generate code (classes per table) compiles and it looks correct.

Comment: object of table class name in DBContext is same as the generated Class?